# Java: How should I create a binary tree given binary codes

Tags: java, tree

Say I have 2 leaves {1,2} and I was given their binary codes (**same length**), meaning that I should construct the binary tree based on the binary codes. And after constructing the binary tree, if I traverse the tree, I should retrieve the same binary codes for leave 1 and 2.

The data format is as follow:

```
leave : binary code
    1: 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1
    2: 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1
```

For example, when the binary code is `0 1 1 0`, I start from the root of the tree and I go left when I see `0` and right when I see `1` ...

**Question**: How can I construct a binary tree based on the binary code given ? (Please note that I am in fact dealing with 200000 leaves , and hence 200000 lines of binary code. So I need an efficient method to do this.)

Comment: I don't think I get it. Two leaves makes a very small binary tree.

Comment: prefix sounds like you are trying to work with a mathematical evaluator? is that correct?  or If not what exactly do you mean by prefix code?, also which traversal method should give you the exact prefix code, inorder, postorder, preorder?

Comment: What is a prefix code?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at this

http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spring01/cs126/assignments/prefix.html

this should hopefully give you insight on what you need to do to create the tree you want